# Migrate or convert SQL Server stored procedures and UDFs to PostgreSQL stored procedure and UDF

Tags: c#, sql-server, postgresql, open-source

I came across with requirement where I have SQL Server database with tables, views, functions and stored procedures in the database. I am able to generate tables, export database to PostgreSQL, but unfortunately I am unable to convert or migrate user-defined functions and stored procedures compatible with PostgreSQL.

I have tried many open sources:

[resource link 1](https://github.com/dalibo/sqlserver2pgsql)

[resource link 2](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1068276/Convert-SQL-Server-Database-to-PostgreSQL)

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public static void ConvertMSSQLToPostgreSQL(string input, string outputFilePath)
{
    // Define a dictionary of data type mappings from MSSQL Server to PostgreSQL
    var dataTypeMappings = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "INT", "INTEGER" },
        { "BIGINT", "BIGINT" },
        { "SMALLINT", "SMALLINT" },
        { "FLOAT", "FLOAT" },
        { "REAL", "REAL" },
        { "NUMERIC", "NUMERIC" },
        { "MONEY", "MONEY" },
        { "BIT", "BOOLEAN" },
        { "CHAR", "CHAR" },
        { "VARCHAR", "VARCHAR" },
        { "TEXT", "TEXT" },
        { "DATE", "DATE" },
        { "TIME", "TIME" },
        { "DATETIME", "TIMESTAMP" }
    };

    // Define a dictionary of operator mappings from MSSQL Server to PostgreSQL
    var operatorMappings = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "=", "=" },
        { "<>", "<>" },
        { "!=", "<>" },
        { "<", "<" },
        { "<=", "<=" },
        { ">", ">" },
        { ">=", ">=" },
        { "+", "+" },
        { "-", "-" },
        { "*", "*" },
        { "/", "/" },
        { "%", "%" },
        { "AND", "AND" },
        { "OR", "OR" },
        { "NOT", "NOT" }
    };

    // Define a regular expression pattern to match data type names
    var dataTypePattern = string.Join("|", dataTypeMappings.Keys);

    // Define a regular expression pattern to match operator names
    var operatorPattern = string.Join("|", operatorMappings.Keys);

    // Define a regular expression pattern to match stored procedure parameters
    var parameterPattern = @"(@\w+)\s+(?:" + dataTypePattern + @")(\([^)]+\))?";

    // Define a regular expression pattern to match operators in SQL code
    var operatorReplacePattern = @"(?<![\w\d])(" + operatorPattern + @")(?![\w\d])";

    // Define a regular expression pattern to match data type names in SQL code
    var dataTypeReplacePattern = @"(?<![\w\d])(" + dataTypePattern + @")(?![\w\d])";

    // Replace data type names and operators in the SQL code with their PostgreSQL equivalents
    var output = Regex.Replace(input, dataTypeReplacePattern, match => dataTypeMappings[match.Value]);
    output = Regex.Replace(output, operatorReplacePattern, match => operatorMappings[match.Value]);

    // Replace stored procedure parameters with PostgreSQL equivalents
    output = Regex.Replace(output, parameterPattern, match =>
    {
        var parameterName = match.Groups[1].Value;
        var dataType = match.Groups[2].Success ? match.Groups[2].Value.TrimStart('(').TrimEnd(')') : "VARCHAR";
        return parameterName + " " + dataTypeMappings[dataType];
    });

    // Write the new PostgreSQL stored procedure to a text file
    File.WriteAllText(outputFilePath, output);
}
```

I have also tried to convert using UDF in MSSQL to generate a query for PostgreSQL

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_sp_to_postgres](@sp_name sysname) RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @schema_name sysname = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(OBJECT_ID(@sp_name));
  DECLARE @sp_base_name sysname = OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID(@sp_name));
  DECLARE @arg_types nvarchar(max) = '';
  DECLARE @arg_names nvarchar(max) = '';
  DECLARE @arg_modes nvarchar(max) = '';
  DECLARE @sp_def nvarchar(max) = '';

  SELECT @sp_def = definition
  FROM sys.sql_modules
  WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@sp_name);

  -- Check if the stored procedure has any parameters
  IF (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.parameters WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@sp_name))) BEGIN
    SELECT @arg_types = STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(t.name), ',')
    FROM sys.parameters p
    JOIN sys.types t ON p.system_type_id = t.system_type_id AND t.user_type_id = p.user_type_id
    WHERE p.object_id = OBJECT_ID(@sp_name)
   -- ORDER BY p.parameter_id;

    SELECT @arg_names = STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(p.name), ',')
    FROM sys.parameters p
    WHERE p.object_id = OBJECT_ID(@sp_name)
  --  ORDER BY p.parameter_id;

    SELECT @arg_modes = STRING_AGG(CASE p.is_output
                                    WHEN 1 THEN 'OUT'
                                    ELSE 'IN'
                                  END + ' ' + QUOTENAME(p.name) + ' ' + QUOTENAME(t.name), ',')
    FROM sys.parameters p
    JOIN sys.types t ON p.system_type_id = t.system_type_id AND t.user_type_id = p.user_type_id
    WHERE p.object_id = OBJECT_ID(@sp_name)
   -- ORDER BY p.parameter_id;

    SET @arg_types = RIGHT(@arg_types, LEN(@arg_types) - 1);
    SET @arg_names = RIGHT(@arg_names, LEN(@arg_names) - 1);
    SET @arg_modes = RIGHT(@arg_modes, LEN(@arg_modes) - 1);
  END;

  RETURN 'CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ' + QUOTENAME(@schema_name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@sp_base_name) +
         '(' + @arg_modes + ') RETURNS void AS $$' + REPLACE(@sp_def, '$', '$$') +
         '$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;';
END;
```

Nutshell, IT is okay to convert via Stored procedure or C# library.

I have also tried generating scripts for SQL Server using this link:

[Generate scripts for postgresql](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YKJub0zVztE&ab_channel=techsapphire)

Comment: The syntax of these databases is quite different and i'm not sure there are any perfect conversion tools because even semantics and handling of variables etc can differ. For example i don't think postgre can even return data the way SQL Server does. how many procedures and what kind of complexity do you have? you might have to do it by hand...

Comment: I have more than 150 stored procedures and It would be difficult to do it manually one by one. Moreover there are some complex stored procedure with Cases, If and temp tables